# How to delete a key value pair in Firestore without using dot notation

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore

My structure looks like this:

```
Firestore
--- collection: Restaurant
------- field: Managers (of type map)
------------ john.appleseed : 110909
------------ sarah.malak : 890758
```

I cannot use the use the arrayRemove because then it removes all of the entries.
And I cannot use the dot notation because my strings contain dots and those are not being recognized hence not deleted.

Comment: Instead of describing how your database looks like, please add a screenshot of it. Besides that, you are trying to remove an entry within that `Managers` map or the entire document?

Answer (score 0):

There are some ways that you can achieve deleting multiples values from your Collection, using id as to check which documents will be deleted. The below code - based on the post from the Community [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52237393/how-to-delete-multiple-documents-that-have-different-ids-in-firestore) - demonstrates an example of deleting documents per id of the `Managers`.

```
WriteBatch batch = db.batch();

for (String id : idsList) {
    DocumentReference ref = db.collection("Managers").document(id);
    batch.delete(ref);
}

batch.commit();
```

I would recommend you to check the above post and this other one below, for more information on how to achieve the deletion of multiple documents.

- [How to model this structure to handle delete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49125183/how-to-model-this-structure-to-handle-delete)

Besides that, there is the additional information on the official documentation [Delete data from Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/delete-data), in case you want to check further details.

Let me know if the information helped you!

Answer (score 0):

The following works on another language. Using the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/delete-data#fields), here is the port to Java:

```
DocumentReference ref = db.collection("Restaurant").document("Managers");

Map<String, Object> updates = new HashMap<String, Object>();
updates.put("john.appleseed", FieldValue.delete());

ref.update(changes).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {});
```

Hopefully this is not too far off (I cannot test with Java).