# How to unify this two instructions?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

Is it possible to unify in a single instruction these two Firestore document set/update?

```
await batchArray[batchIndex].set(finref, doc2.data());
     
await batchArray[batchIndex].update(finref, {"esito" : 1, "timestamp": currentTime});
```

Where "finref" is a document reference and doc2 is a DocumentSnapshot

Comment: Have you tried `await batchArray[batchIndex].set(finref, {...doc2.data(), ...{"esito" : 1, "timestamp": currentTime}});` ?

Comment: Syntax error while writing this await batchArray[batchIndex].set(finref, {doc2.data(), {"esito" : 1, "timestamp": currentTime}});

Comment: Try `await batchArray[batchIndex].set(finref, {...doc2.data(), ...{"esito" : 1, "timestamp": currentTime}});` not `await batchArray[batchIndex].set(finref, {doc2.data(), {"esito" : 1, "timestamp": currentTime}});`. I used spread syntax there

Comment: @ponury-kostek sorry didn't know about spread syntax, I searched it and read the documentation now. The solution in working fine, if you want to post it as answer I'll mark as accepted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can merge those two objects using [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#spread_in_object_literals) and pass it to single command.

```
await batchArray[batchIndex].set(finref, {
  ...doc2.data(),
  ...{
    "esito": 1,
    "timestamp": currentTime
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to perform both operations at once, then you can execute multiple write operations as a [single batch](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#node.js_2) that contains any combination of `set()`, `update()`, or even `delete()` operations. A batch of writes completes atomically, meaning that all operations will succeed or all will fail.

As you can see in the docs, the first argument is always a document reference. If you already have a document snapshot, then you need to get the document reference out of that object in order to commit the batch.

**Edit:**

If you try to update a document, that doesn't exist, indeed you'll get an error that says "No document to update". In that case, you should consider using [`set()` with `merge: true`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#set_a_document). This means that, if the document does **not** exist, then it will be created, and if the document does exist, the data will be merged into the existing document.

Comment: I'm alredy working in this way, but I want to unify set/update because sometimes I have this error: No document to update. I think that by unifying the two instruction in a single .set I'll fix. I don't know if it is possible to do so with a DocumentSnapshot and single fields.

Comment: Thank you for the solution. But in my use case I prefer the other comment approach because I want to update the document with "esito" and "timestamp" only if the document is succesfully created with doc2.data().